# ASCII value for all character in string

Tags: c#, ascii

```
string txt="sentence";
```

I'am trying to get ascii value for every character in string how can i do this in C# winforms?

Comment: Given that C# doesn’t actually store string values in ASCII encoding (and that ASCII is completely obsolete and no modern software uses it), chances are that’s not really what you want – you probably want either the character code or the *actual* encoding value instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
string txt = "sentence";
int[] asciiArray = txt.Select(r => (int)r).ToArray();
```

Later for output you can do:

```
foreach (var item in asciiArray)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

You will get:

```
115
101
110
116
101
110
99
101
```

But remember this will not be limited to ASCII values, if the character is Unicode you will get its integer representation.

You can do that with a simple `foreach` loop like:

```
string txt = "sentence";
foreach (char c in txt)
    Console.WriteLine((int)c);
```

Or a `for` loop like:

```
string txt = "sentence";
for (int i = 0; i < txt.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine((int)txt[i]);
```

The important point is casting it to `int` to get the int value, which for ASCII characters would be `ASCII` value.

Comment: oh i see i did it with for loop before

Comment: @Zeref, you can do it with foreach like `foreach (char c in txt) Console.WriteLine((int)c);`

Answer (score 3):

C# strings are UTF-16 encoded *Unicode*, not ASCII. That means each `char` is a 16-bit unsigned value. A particular Unicode *glyph* may be represented by 1 or 2 such 16-bit values.

The "proper" way to get the ASCII values is to use the ASCII encoding class:

```
string s     = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" ;
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( s ) ;
```

Since ASCII only covers the range 0x00–0x7F (128 characters), any code points outside that range are converted to 0x3f (`'?'`).

Consider using UTF-8 or at least an encoding that will support 0x00-0xFF (`Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")`), so as to prevent data loss.